# On OpenRC is there any conditionals like --ifcrashed?

Tags: openrc

I want execute a command if a given service is crashed, but I only found that conditionals:

```
sudo openrc -s <service> --ifstarted <command>
sudo openrc -s <service> --ifstopped <command>
sudo rc-service <service> --ifexists <command>
sudo rc-service <service> --ifinactive <command>
sudo rc-service <service> --ifnotstarted <commmand>
```

And no one of them is triggered only when a service status is crashed.